# Ms Access how to get the day name in ms access sql query ie. Tuesday

Tags: ms-access, date

I would like to include the name of the day in my query in ms access?
I know how to do it from the query designer in the format field as 'dddd', but want to rather add it in the sql editor as part of my statement.

Its part of a select, from, where, group by, order by statement where the date is specified in the where clause but i want it to display as the name of the day ie Tuesday in another column.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Format works for queries, too:

```
SELECT ADate, Format([ADate],"dddd") AS ADay
FROM Table1;
```

Comment: The function `Format` will not work if **MS Excel object library** has not been added to the references since Format is an Excel function, not an Access function. If so, try `TAB + F11 > Tools > References` and add `Microsoft excel Object Library`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a select statement that returns you the day name from the date time

```
SELECT datename(dw,GETDATE()) AS 'Day Name'
```

This gives me the current day name.

Comment: I think there is no `datename` function in Access, it is a SQL Server function